# unable to click on element with webdriverio

Tags: angularjs, selenium, css-selectors, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am trying to click on a Button using webdriverio/mocha framework
the code look like this:

```
describe ('Mytest', function () {
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.url('/');
})
    it ('should click', function () {
        browser.click("[ng-click='startApplication()']");
    });
});
```

but I got the following error:

> Error: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

I have also tried XPath: `(//A[@ng-activate=''])[1]`

and got same error:

Below is the CSS for those buttons

```
<div class="select-type__wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- ngIf: device === 'phone' -->
      <!-- ngIf: device !== 'phone' -->
      <div ng-if="device !== 'phone'" class="block ng-scope">
        <a ng-activate="" ng-click="startApplication('?json=true')" class="btn btn-answer first ng-scope ng-click-active"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- end ngIf: device !== 'phone' -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- ngIf: device === 'phone' -->
      <!-- ngIf: device !== 'phone' -->
      <div ng-if="device !== 'phone'" class="block second ng-scope">
        <a ng-activate="" ng-click="startApplication('?parent-user=true&amp;json=true')" class="btn btn-answer ng-scope">
      </div>
      <!-- end ngIf: device !== 'phone' -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to make sure, the HTML elements are loaded in time, would `browser.click("#myButton");` work for an HTML tag with ID, like `<a id="myButton" ng-activate="" ng-click="startApplication('?json=true')" ...>`?

Comment: Is `browser.url` invocation like that in your code, or did you change it for purpose of this post, to protect real URL of website you are testing? Because `/` is highly unlikely to open any website in most real-world situations.

Comment: I change it on purpose to protect the site and yes it loaded on time.

Comment: Can you use [browser.getSource()](http://webdriver.io/api/property/getSource.html) instead of `browser.click()` to verify page source as it is seen by webdriver at the moment of click attempt? If there is dynamic creation/loading of elements that you are not telling us about, it may explain your error message.

Comment: is I use `.getSource` all elements of the site are being loaded and there is no dynamic creation/loading of any elements on this page.

Comment: I would *not* suggest using xpath with the full path. This will couple your test highly to the layout of the page. Actually, the same applies for a CSS selector containing a function name of your controller (**startApplication()**). 
From my point of view, giving the tag an **ID attribute** is a good fit. So the test gets exactly the element, you want it to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector looks for elements with attribute `ng-click` that has value `startApplication()`. However, there is no such element in your HTML structure. There are two elements that invoke `startApplication()` function on `ng-click`, but in both cases, that function takes an attribute.

You can select any element with `ng-click` attribute (regardless of its value) using

- CSS: `[ng-click]`
- XPath: `//*[@ng-click]`

If there are many elements with `ng-click` attribute, but you want only these that invoke `startApplication()` (regardless of function argument), you can use:

- CSS: `[ng-click^=startApplication]`
- XPath: `//*[contains(@ng-click, "startApplication")]`

Comment: You were rigtht but even though  I change it to
`browser.click("//*[contains(@ng-click, 'startApplication')]");`
still getting same error.
 Even if I use the full xpath
`//*[@id="inner-content"]/section/div/div/div[2]/div/a`

Comment: @Danny Ahumada  try using `browser.click('[ng-click^=startApplication]')` as suggested above